# Do I need to allocate memory for each node in Linked List in C language using struct?

Tags: c

I have one structure that contains pointer to another structure Node. This pointer is a front pointer to the struct Linked List. So, I am building my link list and each time I insert node I create separate structure and link in to other LL nodes.

**Question:** do I need to allocate memory for each node in LL? Meaning using malloc such as
`*pointer_to_struct = (structAlias *)malloc(sizeof(structAlias));`
and then to initialize its members.

Or I simply create structure and give values to it's members (members are void * and structAlias *next) without memory allocating for each struct?

Comment: Unless, you want to save your link list in a file as an object, you do not need to allocate memory for structure.

Comment: If you don't want to save any information in linked list then why are you creating it?

Answer (score 4):

In the general case, yes, you must allocate memory for each node in the list, and you will probably want to use either `malloc` or `calloc`.  If you just declare a `struct` local variable, that local variable will be invalidated when the function returns, but you probably want the node to outlive the function call.